# How to determinate Target Platform of project via EnvDTE.Project interface

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I am trying to determinate the target platform of Visual Studio project via automation model. However i still do not succeed in this. Does anybody know how to obtain project's target platform with DTE (Any CPU/x86/x64)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Visual Studio macro that will print out the target platform of the active project to the macro output window when run with F5 from the macro IDE:

```
Public Sub ShowProjectPlatform()

    Dim project As Project = CType(CType(DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects, Object())(0), Project)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TargetPlatform = " & project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item("PlatformTarget").Value)

End Sub
```